Undocumented and/or Unusable Google Chrome Extension Permissions?
I noticed some odd permissions in the manifest for the Chrome Extension Chromebook Recovery Utility.
I have omitted parts of the manifest for the sake of brevity, but it is as follows.
{
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Recovery Extension Tool"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background_ext.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chromeos/recovery/recovery2.json",
    "https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chromeos/recovery/cloudready_recovery2.json",
    "https://www.google-analytics.com/"
  ]
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "88",
  "permissions": [
    "chromeosInfoPrivate",
    "feedbackPrivate",
    "fileSystem",
    "imageWriterPrivate",
    "metricsPrivate",
    "storage"
  ],
  "version": "0.2.3"
}

The permissions key value pair is of particular interest.
A large amount of those values are not available in Google's documented Permissions List.
I am very interested in creating an extension that would need similar permissions, but I am not sure if I am running up against some internal proprietary permissions.
I can't find anything definitive on the topic, and was looking for more information about these permissions.

These are private API which can be used only by an extension with this id. This is hard-coded in the source code of Chromium. If you want to use them, copy "key" into your manifest.json and load the extension in unpacked mode. You can't do it in a published extension.
